# Retrieving 10,000 rows from web service and inserting into OWC11 spreadsheet

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

My call to the web service currently is taking too long to come back.  The ASP.NET page takes around one minute or longer to start loading.  I am using C# Response.Write() to write the necessary data to Javascript so Javascript will then insert it into OWC11 spreadsheet.  I want to do this in chunks but I do not know how.

I appreciate your help and/or advice.

Comment: Which part is taking "too long"? Is it the time it takes to Write the document or before? Or is it the time it takes for the JS to run locally?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that their are no bottle necks in your webservice method and the sql query behind it

So in order to speed up the process of get the 10,000 rows my suggestion would be for you to call the webservice with get records of e.g 2000 rows so this way you will make 5 calls

once have the 10,000 rows from the webservice write it to your OWC11 spreadsheet

Else if possible return 5 OWC11 spread sheet each showing 2000 rows persheet

Comment: That did not answer "how".  I am aware of doing it chunks as I mentioned it in the question.  I've attempted AJAX but browser freezes.  Anyway I was able to put a loading notification for the user and speed up code displaying to the browser which helped everything get to the user much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I think in server you should create a thread to receive the response from web service and at client-side you should use AJAX to check process after for example 5 or 10 seconds, you are using single thread, so that is a bottle-neck. You can see the example at Windows Azure portal when you upload your package. Hope this help.